# Lookups with multiple criteria in different sheets (Excel/Sheets)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14DjVgC_WYKSOYyDJwwlDOq45f1Ku8Op9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108133721563589506729&rtpof=true&sd=true

Above is the link for the file and I am trying to fetch data from Greige Data Sheet into individual sheets. I tried indexing by taking help from online resources available but couldn't get any benefit from it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What exactly did you try?

Comment: There are google sheets array formulas in your file and you tag it for Excel and name it in the title as well. Also the question is not really describing what you expect

Comment: see below.  Assuming you've uploaded to g-sheets from Excel - hopefully adequate cross-over for functions to work otherwise (alternatively download to excel and share another way, i.e. one drive etc. as req.)  cheers

Comment: @markfitzpatrick: "*trying to fetch data from xyz Sheet*"...

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hIw28f4YhC6ka44KKg?e=dMWick) refer:

**Caveats**

- *Functions require Office 365 compatibility (not nec. 100% compatible with Sheets - untested)*
- *Functions longer than usual due to inconsistent table header names and label names in respective worksheets (e.g. "METTER" vs "METER" etc.) and light testing on my part RE: `let` parameter/fns*

---

**Beam # (cell B14)**

```
=LET(x_,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table_13[BEAM],--(1*Table_13[LOT]=1*$J$3)))),y_,INDEX(x_,(COLUMNS($A14:B14)/2),1),y_)
```

[image: Beam #]

*Notes: copy / paste to D14, F14 etc. as req.*

---

**LOOM #** (cell B13, D13, etc.)

```
=INDEX(Table_13[LOOM],MATCH(B14,Table_13[BEAM],0))
```

[image: Loom #]

*notes: as before*

---

**DOFF # & METER #**

```
=LET(x0_,IF(A14="",1*B14,IFERROR(1*A14,1*B14)),x_,FILTER(Table_13,--(1*Table_13[LOT]=1*$J$3)*(Table_13[BEAM]*1=x0_)),a_,1*ROWS(A17:A25)*(COUNTIFS($B14:B14,x0_)-1)/2,y_,INDEX(x_,SEQUENCE(MIN(ROWS(A17:A25),ROWS(x_)-a_),1,a_+1,1),MATCH(MID(A16,1,3),MID(Table_13[#Headers],1,3),0)),z_,IFERROR(y_,""),z2_,FILTER(z_,--(y_<>"")),z3_,IFERROR(z2_,""),z3_)
```

[image: Doff & Meter]

*notes*

- *copy / paste into B17,C17,.. etc. (i.e. same function works for both Doff and Meter lookups)*
- *Array / spill function (i.e. only need to apply to first cell eg. A17, required list will 'spill')*
- *dependent upon respective Lot# & Beam # (e.g. Doff/Meter in cols A,B relate to Beam # cell B14; C,D relate to D14 etc.) - Beam #dependent upon Lot number (cell J3 I think)*
- ***Additional feature**: if insufficient rows avail. for all dofs/meters assoc. with a given beam #, entering the same beam # will allow the respective lists to continue as req. (i.e. without repeating pvs doff/meters for the beam# in Q).*
- *Assumes distinct loom # for each beam #*
- *Unsure how to produce Beam Length given the data provided (same goes or various other values, e.g WEFT etc.)*

---